# Return First Letter of Line in File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pull the first letter of every line in a file, then print those letters to a new file. I am working step-by-step so I created the code that would be able to pull the first letter of every line, however, when I added the code to read a specific file it appears that it is not properly iterating over the entire files content. Does anyone know why my for loop is not iterating? Or perhaps, is the issue that it is iterating but not properly adding the letters to 'lines'.

```
def secret2(m):
    infile = open(m, 'r')
    text = infile.read()
    for line in text:
        lines = text[0]
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text[i] == '\n':
                lines += text[i+1]
            print(lines)
            return(lines)
        m.close()
```

Output:

```
>>> secret2('file.txt')
A
'A'
>>>
```

Proper output would be:

```
>>> secret2('file.txt')
'ALICE'
>>>
```

Comment: `for line in text:` is not actually reading lines... It's reading characters.

Comment: @cricket_007 Is that due to my usage of the read() function? Meaning, does read() by default go char-by-char? Oh, I think I see, or I need to add  (+=) to lines = text[0] outside the loop?

Comment: `read()` takes the entire file as one string. A for loop over a string goes char by char. You could have done `for line in infile`, but the one line approach below is what I would use

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you so much for helping me understand the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is iterating over the characters instead of lines. You could print the first character from each line with following code:

```
def secret2(m):
    with open(m) as infile:
        print(''.join(line[0] for line in infile if line))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider the each line as a single data. So use `readlines()` instead of `read`. So your code should be

```
def secret2(m):
    infile = open(m, 'r')
    text = infile.readlines()
    for j in (text):
        print j[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def get_1st_chr(your_file, id_line) :
    with open(your_file) as f :
        text_splitted = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    return text_splitted[id_line][0]
```

Or, if you want all of the first lines character:

```
def get_1st_chr(your_file, nb_lines) :
    with open(your_file) as f :
        text_splitted = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    for i in range(nb_lines) :
        print(text_splitted[[i][0])
```

You could replace `0` with the id of the character you want to print of course.